# Connect to MySQL in eclipse java ee

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, web-applications

I'm getting an error when I try to log on at localhost:8080

I've connected to a database (mysql) which contains employee_id and password columns which the java application will check with to validate the login. But it is returning an error. I have attached all my files below as well as the error.

Login.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String employee_id = request.getParameter("employee_id");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    if(Validate.checkUser(employee_id, password)) { 
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
       out.println("Employee ID or Password is incorrect. Please try again.");
       RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
       rs.include(request, response);
    }
}  


    }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login" method="post">
<h3>
Employee Login
</h3>
<b>Employee ID:</b> <br>
<input type="text"name="employee_id" size="20"><br><br>
<b>Password:</b><br>
<input type="password" name="password" size="20"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Validate.java

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Validate
{
public static boolean checkUser(String employee_id, String password)
{
    boolean st = false;
    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

        Connection con =      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll", "root", ""); 
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_login where employee_id =? and password = ?");
        ps.setString(1, employee_id);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
         st = rs.next();

     }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
         return st;                 
  }   
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Welcome</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

AND I"M GETTING THIS ERROR WHEN I TRY TO LOG IN:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at Validate.checkUser(Validate.java:8)
at Login.doPost(Login.java:15)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: download mysql jdbc driver add it to classpath

Comment: @Ramanlfc Yes I have the driver but I am unsure of the code to write. By the way, could you please tell me the difference between a class and a servlet?

Comment: put the jar in `WEB-INF/lib` and servlet is just  java class which is protocol independent but it is generally used with http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Connect Database Using Servlet Using This Code. But You Must have to Bbbbbbulid class Path Using `mysqljdbc` Driver or download Jar .

```
public class ServletDatabaseConnect extends HttpServlet  
{
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
{
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("text/html");        
    String tb=req.getParameter("table");    

    try
    {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","admin");
         Statement st=con.createStatement();
         System.out.println("connection established successfully...!!");     

         ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from "+tb);


             while(rs.next())
             {
                 pw.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td>"+
                                  "<td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td></tr>");
             }
         pw.println("</table>");
         pw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

Comment: `Class.forName()` is redundant nowadays

Comment: @Ramanlfc When I try to log in, it gives an error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Can you please check my code? I'll upload it

Comment: Download : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver jar and add it on your Project . jar link : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm

Comment: @AnandDwivedi mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar is already in my library

Comment: why reject answer .? btw jdbc jar on your Project lib ? .other way is  Right Click the project -- > build path -- > configure build path In Libraries Tab press Add External Jar and Select your jar.

Comment: @AnandDwivedi Yes I already have the jdbc jar in project lib, I don't know why it's not working. And I rejected answer because maybe other people will think the problem is completely gone. Don't worry, I'll accept your answer now, but can you please help me fix, why it's giving that error.